# What is the definitive (android compatible) RSS/Atom processing library?

Tags: java, android, rome

I've been told by long-time Java developers that Apache's Rome module is the definitive library for reading & generating RSS & Atom feeds.

I've had a look at the library - it does not seem to be under active development right now. Is this really the best available? Specifically, I'm trying to write an Android application which will read in a number of feeds. I'm worried that Apache Rome might be to heavyweight for a handheld device.

Are there any alternatives that I ought to consider? My main criteria are:

- Lightweight enough to run on a low-power device.
- Easy to use API

Comment: if the xml you will parse isn't crazy complex, just roll your own parser using a SAX Parser or whatever.

Comment: I'd really rather not spend the time re-inventing this particular wheel. The XML in question are typical RSS/Atom feeds generated by blogging software (e.g. wordpress). They typically contain errors, hence the need for a very robust parsing tool.

Answer (score 7):

There is a repackaged version of Rome for Android: http://code.google.com/p/android-rome-feed-reader/.  I know it is used by the Spring Android library.

Comment: Excellent, I will check it out.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. I spent a day trying to get Rome working in my Android application project, because of it's half assed java.beans.x implementation. Sadly I saw it afterwards :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Android linter sees that this repackaged jar contains refs to java.awt, java.applet, etc. Not a clean Android library.

Answer (score 1):

For a recent project I tried all available methods for parsing rss and came to the conclusion that http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html is the most decent one you might use. Easy to use and performant enough to run on low powered devices as well.

Comment: This has the benefit of being part of the standard library, but I'm worried that I'd have to do a lot of work to implement all of the various oddities found in feeds.

Comment: Of course, this will work. But the OP said he didn't want to reinvent the wheel, and is explicitly seeking for a RSS and a Atom library, not a general purpose XML parsing framework.

Comment: Then this question makes no sense to my mind. No lib can guess what you actually want to do with the rss feed.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me: I'm just after a lib (something like Rome) which can make the job of parsing the kind of RSS/Atom we see on the web much easier. Even though feed XML is quite a simple format there are real-world complexities which make parsing into quite a challenge (if you want to do it robustly). If I were to hand-roll this component to a good standard it might take me as much time as the rest of the project!

Answer (score 1):

There is also this library I wrote:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It uses a fluent API for easy usage, it's very lightweight + fast, supports custom feed item properties, and is compatible with most RSS2 feeds by default but allows you to plug in your own custom RssParser to support all kinds of feeds.